# VS Code "Terminal" runs code but "Output" does not

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I recently got an RTX 3070 and have been trying to get the latest tf-nightly-gpu work with it for machine learning. However, I think my issue might be unrelated. While using the "Output" only TensorFlow throws and error, every other module works. I'm using an anaconda environment, python 3.8.5, and my anaconda paths are set up in my system variables. I'm completely lost and have no idea what to do. Maybe it's something with the shell but I don't know how that stuff works. (Similar issue answers didn't fix my problem) [image: Output Error] [image: Terminal running program]

Comment: are you unable to copy-paste the terminal text

Comment: Add the following code before the `import` sentences to check if **Code Runner** used the current python interpreter: `import sys          print(sys.executable)`.

Comment: @MollyWang Interesting, it's using the default environment even though I have the correct one selected on the bottom left. Perhaps my VS Code is configured wrong?

Comment: No, Code Runner didn't use the current interpreter, which is saved in pythonpath. When you manually set  pythonpath as code runner executor path, it start working. now i'm happy your question had been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my setting.json fixed my issue:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
        },
```